# Pyro call over WAN

Tags: pyro

I have a Pyro4 application that needs to be accessed by users globally. Users from within the US can access it fine. However, a user from a London PC seems to have issues connecting to the server. He can ping the nameserver correctly, but gets a Pyro CommunicationError ([Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed) when executing an actual call on the proxy.

Has anyone seen this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that when I created the daemon and registered it with the nameserver, I didn't use the fully qualified hostname (aka socket.getfqdn()). As a result it could find the remote object over the local network but not across the WAN.